# Invoke FlowLayoutPanel Mousedown handler when clicked child control

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I am working in `VS 2010`, Windows Form control.

I have a extended `FlowLayoutPanel`, in which I dynamically add buttons

My problem is that the `MouseDownEventhandler` for `flowlayout planel` only executes when clicked anywhere except the buttons.
`When clicked on button the MouseDownEventHandler for the FlowLayoutPanel is not called`.

I tried wiring function to the Click event handlers of the buttons added to the Panel.
but I noticed delays due to which I am having issues working ahead.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is propably not the best approch but it works for me:

```
//global mouse down handler for controls in flow panel
private void ControlMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (Control)sender;

    if (control.Parent is FlowLayoutPanel)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1_MouseDown(sender, e); //if you have seperate method to handle click on flowpanel otherwise see reflection approach below
    }
}
```

Reflection approach:

```
var onMouseDown = flowLayoutPanel1.GetType().GetMethod("OnMouseDown", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
onMouseDown.Invoke(flowLayoutPanel1, new object[] { e });
```

You can bind global event to all child controls in flow panel easly and this works okey for me. Hope I helped :)